# How do you compress multiple folders at a time, using a shell?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, for-loop

There are **n** folders in the directory named after the date, for example:

20171002 20171003 20171005 ...20171101 20171102 20171103 ...20180101 20180102

**tips:** Dates are not continuous.
I want to compress every three folders in each month into one compression block.
For example:

```
tar jcvf mytar-20171002_1005.tar.bz2 20171002 20171003 20171005
```

How to write a shell to do this?

Comment: Are there always 3 folders for a month or could it just be 2 and those should be compressed? Or could there be more than 3 and only the first three should be compressed?

Comment: If only two folders this month, I put the two compressed into one, if there are 10 folder this month, so the former 9 need to be compressed into three, the rest of the folders compressed for a alone, a total of four

Comment: What have you tried? 
Is your problem about the for loop on folder, or to parse their name?

Comment: I tried to compress a single folder with the for loop, but multiple folder compression I didn't figure out how to write it?It is the compressed document that shows what files are included.mytar-20171002_1005.tar.bz2 so named representative contains 20171002 folder in the beginning, the end of the 20171005 folder, if the compressed file is only a document composition to write their own names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a for loop on your `ls` variable, then parse the directory name.

```
dir_list=$(ls)
prev_month=""
times=0
first_dir=""
last_dir=""
dir_list=()
for i in $dir_list; do 
   month=${i:0:6} #here month will be year plus month
   if [ "$month" = "$prev_month" ]; then 
      i=$(($i+1))
      if [ "$i" -eq "3" ]; then 
          #compress here 
          dir_list=()
          first_dir=""
          last_dir=""
      else 
          last_dir=$i
          dir_list+=($i)
      fi
   else
     if [ "$first_dir" = "" ]; then 
         first_dir=$i
     else 
         #compress here 
         first_dir="$i"
         last_dir=""
         dir_list=()
     fi 
   fi
```

This code is not tested and may contain syntaxe error. '#compress here' need to be replace by a loop on the array to create a string to compress.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have too many directories (I think the limit is several hundred), then you can use Bash's array manipulation.

So, you first load all your directory names into a Bash array:

```
dirs=( $(ls) )
```

(I'm going to assume files have no spaces in their names, otherwise it gets a bit dicey)

Then you can use Bash's array slice syntax to pop 3 elements at a time from the array:

```
while [ "${#dirs[@]}" -gt 0 ]; do
    dirs_to_compress=( "${dirs[@]:0:3}" )
    dirs=( "${dirs[@]:3}" )
    # do something with dirs_to_compress
done
```

The rest should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
unset folders
declare -A folders
g=3
for folder in $(ls -d */); do
    folders[${folder:0:6}]+="${folder%%/} "
done
for folder in "${!folders[@]}"; do
    for((i=0; i < $(echo ${folders[$folder]} | tr ' ' '\n' | wc -l); i+=g)) do
        group=(${folders[$folder]})
        groupOfThree=(${group[@]:i:g})
        tar jcvf mytar-${groupOfThree[0]}_${groupOfThree[-1]:4:4}.tar.bz2 ${groupOfThree[@]}
    done
done
```

This script finds all folders in the current directory, seperates them in groups of months, makes groups of at most three folders and creates a **.tar.bz2** for each of them with the name you used in the question.

I tested it with those folders:

```
20171101 20171102 20171103  20171002 20171003 20171005 20171007 20171009 20171011 20171013  20180101 20180102
```

And the created tars are:

```
mytar-20171002_1005.tar.bz2
mytar-20171007_1011.tar.bz2
mytar-20171013_1013.tar.bz2
mytar-20171101_1103.tar.bz2
mytar-20180101_0102.tar.bz2
```

Hope that helps :)

EDIT: If you are using bash version < 4.2 then replace the line:

```
tar jcvf mytar-${groupOfThree[0]}_${groupOfThree[-1]:4:4}.tar.bz2 ${groupOfThree[@]}
```

by:

```
tar jcvf mytar-${groupOfThree[0]}_${groupOfThree[`expr ${#groupOfThree[@]} - 1`]:4:4}.tar.bz2 ${groupOfThree[@]}
```

That's because bash version < 4.2 doesn't support negative indices for arrays.

Comment: thanks for your help ,I tried your script but I ran into some problems.

Comment: groupOfThree:bad array subscript

Comment: @user9624737 What version of bash do you have?
And on what line does the syntax erorr occur?

Comment: @user9624737 I updated the answer if you have a lower bash version then 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `xargs`, a bash `while` loop, and `awk`:

```
ls | xargs -n3 | while read line; do
    tar jcvf $(echo $line | awk '{print "mytar-"$1"_"substr($NF,5,4)".tar.bz2"}') $line
done
```

Comment: I put this script in the same level directory as the folders that are being compressed.I tried your script but there was a problem.After running the script, an extra compressed document containing the script is generated.

Comment: tks a lot,i got the result!

Comment: This script mixes folders of different months.